# C++ Why wont this function toggle this interger value?

Tags: c++, xor

```
int Test = 11;


void Toggle(const char* Name, int Offset, int Value){
     Offset ^= Value;
     printf("%s\n [%s^7]", Name, Offset ? "^2ON" : "^1OFF");
}
```

In main...

```
void main(){
    Toggle("Unlimited Ammo", Test, 100);
    Toggle("Unlimited Ammo", Test, 100);
}
```

I'm pretty sure XOR is suppose to toggle this. I don't know why its not working for me.

Comment: Passing parameters by value means that only the local copy will be modified.

Comment: It works for booleans fine. But not with this? I don't understand.

Comment: What do you expect "toggle" to mean?

Comment: Toggling between values as what XOR does.

Comment: A downvote and a vote to close as "off topic"?  Seriously?  Some of you guys are jerks.  Is it really that hard to believe that a beginner would struggle with argument passing semantics?  At least get off your lazy bums and close as a duplicate.

Comment: Can you explain what Toggle(...) is suppose to do, so that we can better help you?

Comment: XOR will "toggle" the bits. `100` is `01100100b` in binary and `11` is `00001011b` in binary. If you "toggle" the bits you get `01101111b` which is 111

Comment: @EdS The vote count is meant to reflect how useful the question is to the content base of this site.  This question is not useful. Mouse over the upvote and downvote buttons to see a description of what they are for.

Comment: @MattMcNabb: Says who?  It's certainly useful to people having the same problem (of which there are many).  Sure, it's a dup, but probably one of the most common errors that a beginner runs into.  Also, let's not pretend that there is no emotional aspect to getting downvoted into oblivion right after joining the site.  Anyway, I probably shouldn't have started the debate to begin with, but at least close it for the correct reason.

Answer (score 0):

C++, by default, is pass by value, meaning the function gets a *local copy* of `Test`. Changes to it are not reflected back to the caller.

If you want pass by reference, you have to use ... wait for it ... *references* :-)

You do that with a function signature like:

```
void Toggle(const char* Name, int &Offset, int Value) ...
```